# Mapstruct - Controlling mapping result for 'null' arguments

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, mapstruct

Good evening :)

I have a project with 2 main classes, Car and Person and I'm trying to map their DTO with mapstruct.

As Car and Person have a one-to-one optional relationship, **I need that Car.owner == null when CarDTO.ownerId == null** Otherwise I'd face problems trying to persist the Car object with a <Person(id=0, name=null, age=0)> attribute.

Here are the classes:

```
package examples.model;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Car {

    private int id;
    private Person owner;
    private int numerOfWheels;
    private int seatingCapacity;
    private double maximumVelocity;
}
```

```
package examples.dto;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class CarDTO {

    private String id;
    private String ownerId;
    private String numerOfWheels;
    private String seatingCapacity;
    private String maximumVelocity;
}
```

```
package examples.model;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Person {

    
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
}
```

```
package examples.mapper;

import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

import examples.dto.CarDTO;
import examples.model.Car;

@Mapper
public interface CarMapper {

    CarMapper MAPPER = Mappers.getMapper(CarMapper.class);
    
    @Mapping(source = "dto.ownerId", target = "owner.id")
    Car toModel(CarDTO dto);
}
```

Here is the mapstruct implementation:

```
package examples.mapper;

import examples.dto.CarDTO;
import examples.model.Car;
import examples.model.Person;
import javax.annotation.processing.Generated;

@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2021-08-03T23:26:30-0300",
    comments = "version: 1.5.0.Beta1, compiler: Eclipse JDT (IDE) 1.3.1300.v20210419-1022, environment: Java 11.0.11 (Ubuntu)"
)
public class CarMapperImpl implements CarMapper {

    @Override
    public Car toModel(CarDTO dto) {
        if ( dto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Car car = new Car();

        car.setOwner( carDTOToPerson( dto ) );
        if ( dto.getId() != null ) {
            car.setId( Integer.parseInt( dto.getId() ) );
        }
        if ( dto.getMaximumVelocity() != null ) {
            car.setMaximumVelocity( Double.parseDouble( dto.getMaximumVelocity() ) );
        }
        if ( dto.getNumerOfWheels() != null ) {
            car.setNumerOfWheels( Integer.parseInt( dto.getNumerOfWheels() ) );
        }
        if ( dto.getSeatingCapacity() != null ) {
            car.setSeatingCapacity( Integer.parseInt( dto.getSeatingCapacity() ) );
        }

        return car;
    }

    protected Person carDTOToPerson(CarDTO carDTO) {
        if ( carDTO == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Person person = new Person();

        if ( carDTO.getOwnerId() != null ) {
            person.setId( Integer.parseInt( carDTO.getOwnerId() ) );
        }

        return person;
    }
}
```

The test:

```
package examples;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import examples.dto.CarDTO;
import examples.mapper.CarMapper;
import examples.model.Car;

class CarMapperTest {

    
    @Test
    public void testMapDtoToEntity() {
        
        
        CarDTO carDTO = new CarDTO();
        carDTO.setMaximumVelocity("115.2");
        carDTO.setNumerOfWheels("4");
        carDTO.setSeatingCapacity("5");
        
        Car car = CarMapper.MAPPER.toModel(carDTO);
        
        assertEquals(115.2, car.getMaximumVelocity() );
        assertEquals(4, car.getNumerOfWheels() );
        assertEquals(5, car.getSeatingCapacity());
        assertEquals(null, car.getOwner());
    }
}
```

The result:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <null> but was: <Person(id=0, name=null, age=0)>
```

Can anybody help me solve this?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it. Change your mapper as below with implementation for your carDto to Person conversion.

```
package examples.mapper;

import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

import examples.dto.CarDTO;
import examples.model.Car;

@Mapper
public abstract class CarMapper {

    CarMapper MAPPER = Mappers.getMapper(CarMapper.class);

    @Mapping(source = "dto", target = "owner")
    public abstract Car toModel(CarDTO dto);

    public Person carDtoToPerson(CarDTO carDto) {
        if (carDto == null || carDto.getOwnerId() == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Person person = new Person();

        if (carDto.getOwnerId() != null) {
            person.setId(Integer.parseInt(carDto.getOwnerId()));
        }

        return person;
    }
}
```